# Dojo Gauge noChange

Tags: dojo, gauge

I have a gauge implemented in dojox using the example on the Dojo [Reference](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/gauges/GlossySemiCircularGauge.html#dojox-gauges-glossysemicirculargauge) site.
I would like the gauge to not react to input from the user. The documentation from the example indicates that the "noChange" parameter should be passed to accomplish this. However when i do this the gauge still accepts input from the user.

I am new to to Dojo and the only thing i have changed is the way in which the modules are loaded for Dojo 1.7 as highlighted in the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/require.html#).

```js
        require(["dojox/gauges/GlossySemiCircularGauge", "dijit/form/Button"], function (GlossySemiCircularGauge, Button) {

        makeGauge = function () {
            var glossyCircular = new dojox.gauges.GlossySemiCircularGauge({
                background: [255, 255, 255, 0],
                title: 'Value',
                id: "semiGlossyGauge",
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                value: 40,
                noChange: false,
            }, dojo.byId("SemiCircularGauge"));
            glossyCircular.startup();
        };
        dojo.ready(makeGauge);
```

I am running Dojo 1.7.1 hosted on ajax.googleapis.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe noChange should be true if you don't want user input.

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9kEE9/1/